# qmake using incorrect paths to Qt installation on linux

Tags: linux, qt, qmake

I compiled qt (qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4) using:

```
./configure --prefix=/edrive/local/qt
gmake && gmake install
```

When I want to make new project with `qmake` in creates Makefile with wrong include paths and points to wrong binaries and library directories:

```
> qmake -query "QT_INSTALL_PREFIX"
/edrive/local
```

in Makefile

includes:

```
-I/edrive/local/include/QtCore
-I/edrive/local/include/QtGui
-I/edrive/local/include
```

libs:

```
-L/edrive/local/lib
```

uic:

```
/edrive/local/bin/uic
```

These are clearly wrong as qt was installed in `/edrive/local/qt`.

Is there a way to fix this short of manually modifying qt config files?
Am I doing something wrong?

Btw, it's selecting correct qmake:

```
> which qmake
/edrive/local/bin/qt/qmake
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change that value with:

```
# qmake -set VARIABLE VALUE
```

I.e. in your case with:

```
# qmake -set QT_INSTALL_PREFIX /edrive/local/qt
```

Although judging from your qmake location, you're calling wrong qmake.
Try

```
/edrive/local/qt/bin/qmake -query "QT_INSTALL_PREFIX"
```

I have a feeling you have 2 Qt installations aside.

Comment: I think I'm calling the correct qmake but qmake is getting it wrong: `> /edrive/local/bin/qt/qmake -query "QT_INSTALL_PREFIX"
/edrive/local` . I tried to set the new path but query still outputs the same result ...

Comment: Well, my point was, if your --prefix was /edrive/local/qt, then path should be /edrive/local/qt/bin, rather than /edrive/local/bin/qt, if you see what I mean.

Nevertheless, you can set the prefix again with `qmake -set`

Comment: I see ... I've killed terminal and restarted, now it all works - strange, I've sourced my profile file couple of times I guess it got confused ....